# Why the PHP can't see a value which is coming from ajax js?

Tags: javascript, php

When I get my result from the JS side the value comes true. But I want to fill the value to my PHP file, so I've used ajax. When I delete if isset function in PHP , I got an "undefined index" error.

HTML Side

```
     <form method="post" onsubmit="return false;"  class="form-inline">
     <input type="email" name="email" id="subscriber_email" placeholder="Your E-mail" >
     <button type="submit" id="subscribe_newsletter" class="btn newsbox-btn w- 
      100"onclick="gonder()">Subscribe</button>
                            
       </form>
       <div id="subscribe_message"></div>
        <p id="succes" class="mt-30"></p>
```

---

jS side

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function gonder(){
var ad=$("input[name='email']").val();

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"myphpfile.php",
    data:ad,   // I also tried  {'sendingData':ad} but it doesn't work.
    success:function(sonuc){
        $("#subscribe_message").html(sonuc);
        $("#succes").html(sonuc);   
        
    }
})

 }
</script>
```

---

And PHP side

```
<?php


    if(isset($_POST["ad"])){
    $x=$_POST["ad"];
    echo $x;

     }
   else{
      echo "There is nothing coming from the script.";

      }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending a value, but you're not sending a *key* with that value.  So for example if the value is `123` then you're only sending `123`, nothing else.  So this won't find it because there's no key called `ad` in the data being sent:

```
$_POST["ad"]
```

Add a key for the value:

```
data: { ad: ad }
```

Or even simply:

```
data: { ad }
```